# How to loop through SQL queries and change one parameter during each iteration

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jupyter

How can I run this SQL query multiple times in a loop, where I replace the word 'awesome' with another word during each iteration. Is there a way to store an array of strings and loop through them?

I am trying to find the reviews in my database that mention the word 'awesome' but I also want to run this query on several other words without having to run them one by one and manually replacing the word 'awesome'

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE review_text LIKE '%awesome%'
```

Comment: put all of the strings into a temp table and then join that temp table to your books using a like statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE SearchStrings (SearchString VARCHAR(50));

INSERT INTO SearchStrings (SearchString)
VALUES ('string1'),('string2');

SELECT *
FROM
    books b
    INNER JOIN SearchStrings s
    ON b.review_text LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%',s.SearchString),'%')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single query you can just append all of the different search text you want to included in a list of ORs in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM books 
WHERE review_text LIKE '%awesome%'
OR review_text LIKE '%blossum%'
OR review_text LIKE '%possum%'
OR review_text LIKE '%bean-soup%'
```

And you can just append as many as you need to search by.  This also has the added benefit of saving you round trips to the database, making this single query much faster than several independent queries.